# Get footprint or boundary of LIDAR data

Tags: raster, dem, lidr, boundaries, footprint

I am using the `lidR` package in R to manage my ALS data. I was having problems generating DTMs on the edge files of my `catalog` because the tool `lidR::grid_terrain()` was doing some interpolation between points that define the boundary of the point cloud. I attach an image presenting the error:
[image: plotting of edge file]
[image: DTM and Slope(degrees) of edge file]

I came up with what I think is just a small fix for my case but maybe is helpfull for a small analysis:

```
las <- readLAS(file)
#projection(las) <- CRS("+init=epsg:REF") #In case it lacks projection

dtm <- grid_terrain(las, res = 1, tin())

p <- raster::rasterToPolygons(lidR::grid_density(las)*0+1, dissolve = TRUE) #To create a mask
m <- raster::mask(raster::crop(dtm, raster::extent(p)),p) #To mask the DTM
```

The result is a DTM perfectly masked to where there are points.
[image: Result of masking]

I was wondering if there is another method for big areas as I am afraid of this could take a long time to process al the files in a catalog.

Comment: Have you tried PDAL https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/boundary/boundary.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple *and* fast solution. Your DTM is indeed incorrect, but only where there are no points. Consequently this problem that is a known issue was considered not big problem.

`grid_terrain()` has a parameter `is_concave = FALSE`. If your turns it to `TRUE` it computes **a** concave hull and interpolates only in the hull. Sadly it is slow to compute and will increase the computation time. You have only ~30 tiles so it can do the job if the point density is not super high. Try it and see if it can works for you.

Your solution is perfectly fine and probably faster. Yet I would try with a larger resolution to avoid the small "holes" I can see in your image. Or maybe fill the holes before to mask.

The [`lidR`](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR) package has a function `catalog_boundaries()` that computes the concave hull of each tile exactly like `grid_terrain()` but that is much faster. You could use the polygons to mask the pixels. You can compute the hull on a thinned point-clouds to go faster.

Comment: I did not know about this package. Thanks for the head up. I have tried increasing the resolution  of ´´´grid_density´´´ and got better results with less holes. I am trying to use the ´´´is_concave = TRUE´´´ parameter but it indicates that this argument is unused and returns Error.

Comment: `ìs_concave` was introduced in lidR 3.1.0

Comment: Just a note that `catalog_boundaries()` is slow for me even with `concavity = Inf`, as in a 3+ hour ETA from lidR 4.0.1 on <15 GB of .laz tiles with a Zen 3 core at 4.8 GHz. Since lasboundary.exe -convex (from LAStools) completes the same task in less than two minutes it may be more efficient to read its shapefiles from R.

Comment: When I have done `ctg2 <- catalog_boundaries(ctg, concavity=1, length_threshold=15)`, and display it with `plot(ctg2, add=TRUE)`, how can I convert the polygon to for example a shapefile

Comment: @BERA you can convert a 'catalog' to a polygon layer by using 'sf::st_as_sf(ctg2)'